# How to force Thrift to only accept connections from the localhost

Tags: c++, thrift

I have a Java application that spins up multiple c++ processes.  It communicates with these processes via Thrift RPC.  For security purposes, I'd like to force the Thrift servers (c++ processes) to only accept connections from the localhost.  I assumed it would be easy to bind the thrift socket to the loopback address, but after some googling I have not found an adequate solution.  Am I missing something?    Is there a way to bind thrift connections to an ip?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with builtin tools.

There is a concept of "processor events" implemented for certain language bindings. Not sure if they are for Java, but that could be worth a try.

Another apoproach would involve the creation of a customized `TTransport` implementation that checks the incoming connection.

Comment: I ended up creating a customized TTransport to check the connection.  Thanks for the advice.